# Trying to snap a group to grid with kineticJS having one shape presently weird offset

Tags: jquery, kineticjs

```
    function draw_shape(sides) {

      var shape_group = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        draggable: true
      });

      var shape_size = 10
      var radius = shape_size / 2
      var shape = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        sides: sides,
        radius: radius,
        fill:'#fff',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        lineJoin: 'bevel'
      });

      shape_group.on('dragmove', function() {
        var current_cell = current_cell_from_mouse_position()
        shape_group.setX(current_cell.x);
        shape_group.setY(current_cell.y);
      });
      shape_group.add(shape);
      board_layer.add(shape_group);
      stage.add(board_layer);
    }
```

in this example current_cell_from_mouse_position() gives me back the correct x and y cordinates. This example works great without the group. I am not sure why but when I add the group a wierd offset is created moving the group and shape to the bottom right.

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the shape's x/y to 10/10 will cause that shape to shift down-right within the group by 10 pixels.

So your **group** is properly aligned to the grid.

But your **shape within the group** is offset by 10 pixels.

Cure: set your shape's x/y to 0,0 instead of 10/10.